# What is controller_group for in view call?

Tags: voltrb

I just wanted to understand better the `view` call in main.hmtl: what is the third parameter `{controller_group: 'main'}` for in:

```
{{ view main_path, "title", {controller_group: 'main'} }}
```

Are there other options or parameters that can be passed to `view`? Sorry if I've missed something in the docs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

controller_group makes it so multiple view bindings can share the same controller instance.  You give it a unique string name between each view binding and it will only load up one.  Otherwise each view (title and body for example) would get its own controller.